# What is the name of an entry in an index?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is the name of an entry in an index? For example, an element of a taxonomy is a taxon and elements of a taxonomy are taxa. What is the equivalent for an index?

Comment: What kind of index? Stock market indexes could have individual stocks as elements; telephone index books have pages or leaves; programming indexes don’t have smaller logical elements; etc. Your own term *entry* is a good generic term for elements of indexed collections.

Comment: It's for an index of websites, but I don't think it matters. There should be a generalized term for an index entry just as a taxon is an element of a taxonomy and a taxonomy is comprised of taxa.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes an element contained in an index is an "entry".

Comment: Good Q. May need to show background effort, though. Good Luck.

Comment: OP has already found it and @WS2 has agreed: **entry** it is.

Comment: Although its use is uncommon, the word "indice" (as opposed to the plural form, "indices") might be a possibility.  Don

Comment: An [index term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_term) is one possible answer. Other possible answers are subject term, subject heading, or descriptor. None of these are particularly satisfying though. Index and subject terms seem too specific to search engines. Subject headings are specific to library cataloging, and descriptor was coined for thesauri.